# Send heroku logs to s3

Tags: logging, heroku, amazon-s3, archiving

Does anyone know a free Heroku add-on for archiving heroku logs on S3 AWS? I used Loggly add-on but it is not free anymore. So I'd like to find an alternative.

I can see there are [flyData](https://addons.heroku.com/flydata) and [logentries](https://logentries.com/) Has anyone used those? Any feedback on them? I would appreciate everyone's thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [PaperTrail](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/papertrail)?

It looks like it does what you're trying to do for free.

> Archives
>
> Papertrail automatically creates compressed log archive files on a daily or hourly basis. These are downloadable in Papertrail under Archives. Archives are retained for 1 year with all paid plans or 1 week with the free “choklad” plan.
> Additionally, **Papertrail can upload these archives to an S3 bucket in your own Amazon Web Services account**. See “Account” to provide a bucket.
> Each archive contains all logs in a tab-separated values (TSV) format. In addition to being human-readable, the TSVs are simple to parse or import into a data warehouse like Redshift or Hive/Hadoop on Elastic MapReduce.

Comment: Papertrail free plan has a 10MB per day limit